# Determine maximum sum of keys subarrays with given max value

Tags: algorithm

I am having two dimensional array as follows:in  pair

```
3,3 
4,3
3,2 
2,2
2,1
```

Now I want to find out subarrays with maximum sum of keys and  whose sum of values =6

different subarrays with sumof values 6 are

```
[[3,3],[4,3]] ,Sum = 7
[[3,3],[3,2],[2,1]] ,Sum = 8
[[3,3],[2,2],[2,1]] ,Sum = 7
[[4,3],[3,2],[2,1]],sum = 9
[[4,3],[2,2],[2,1]],sum =8
```

for above array  elements [4,3] [3,2],[2,1] form subarray with sum of values as 6 ie 3+2+1 =6
Sum of keys of above subarrays = 9,which is maximum

I am not able to think properly if it can solved by DP or basic iteration.Any pointers/hints will help

Comment: Please explain your sum function, i.e. how does `3+3+4+3=7`?

Comment: @ChrisPickford OP means adding only keys. `3+3+2 = 8`

Comment: Those aren't key/value pairs they are array objects.

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved using Dynamic Programming, we can iterate over each index and can either add the current index to the answer or choose to ignore it, then we can you memoisation to reduce the complexity of the problem.

I have written a recursive dynamic programming solution in c++ :

```
#include <iostream>
#define INF 100000000
using namespace std;

int arr[100][2], sumOfValues, n, dp[100][10000];

int solve(int index, int currentSum){
    if(index == n){
        if(currentSum == sumOfValues) return 0;
        else return -INF;
    }
    if(dp[index][currentSum] != -1) return dp[index][currentSum];
    int v1 = solve(index+1, currentSum + arr[index][1]) + arr[index][0];    //take current element
    int v2 = solve(index+1, currentSum);    //do not take current element
    return dp[index][currentSum] = max(v1, v2);
}

int main() {
    n = 5;
    sumOfValues = 6;
    arr[0][0] = 3;arr[0][1] = 3;
    arr[1][0] = 4;arr[1][1] = 3;
    arr[2][0] = 3;arr[2][1] = 2;
    arr[3][0] = 2;arr[3][1] = 2;
    arr[4][0] = 2;arr[4][1] = 1;
    for(int i = 0;i < 100;i++) for(int j = 0;j < 10000;j++) dp[i][j] = -1;
    cout << solve(0, 0) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Link to solution on Ideone : http://ideone.com/HMw9Sf

Note that if the answer returned is `-INF`, that means that no solution was possible for the given sumOfValues.

Comment: I still need to understand your algo , but how do you figure it out that its a DP problem and how did u come up with solution..is this problem some variant of common DP problem?

Comment: @tim tom  This is `Knapsack problem` with exact weight sum.

Comment: It's a varient of subset sum problem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem

Comment: Also note that it is not a polynomial time algorithm, rather a Pseudo-polynomial polynomial time algorithm, by which i mean that it's complexity depends on the input i.e here it depends on the sumOfValues constraint.